Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ with $abc=1$. Show that $a^4+b^4+c^4 \geq a+b+c$
The problem
Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ with $abc=1$. Show that $a^4+b^4+c^4 \geq a+b+c$
My idea
We can write the inequality as $4a^4+4b^4+4c^4\geq 4a^2bc+ 4b^2ac+ 4c^2ab$ which is true by AM-GM ($2a^4+b^4+c^4 \geq 4a^2bc$)
Is my idea right? I am in doubt because the numbers have to be real, and it doesn't specify if they are negative or positive.

Because the question allows for all reals, your solution is likely worth $0^+$. It could depend on the strictness of the grader, but I believe that the phrasing is meant to catch those who blindly use AM-GM without accounting for the non-negative conditions.

Your solution can be fixed by saying that
$$ 2a^4 + b^4 + c^4 \geq 4|a^2bc| = 4|a| \geq 4a.$$
We satisfied the non-negative condition in AM-GM using the terms $a^2, b^2, c^2$.

We need to show for all non-zero $a, b, c \in \mathbb R$, the inequality:
$$a^4 + b^4 + c^4 ≥ a + b + c$$
holds true given that $abc = 1$.
CASE 1: $a, b, c \in \mathbb R^+$
By the AM ≥ GM inequality (for positive reals):
$$\dfrac{2a^4 + b^4 + c^4}{4} ≥ \sqrt[4]{a^4(abc)^4} = a$$
Continuing this process for $b, c$ and then adding all the inequalities up will yield:
$$\therefore a^4 + b^4 + c^4 ≥ a + b + c \longleftarrow \forall\ a, b, c \in \mathbb R^+$$
Note that equality will only hold when $a^4 = b^4 = c^4$ as per the AM ≥ GM inequality. Since this case deals with positive reals, $a = b = c = 1$ will result in equality because $a^4b^4c^4 = 1$.
Case 2: $a, b, c \in \mathbb R$
Now, we include negative reals too. WLOG, suppose that $a < 0$, then another must be negative too, say $b$. From case 1:
$$a^4 + b^4 + c^4 ≥ |a| + |b| + c > a + b + c$$
Thus, we have shown in all cases that:
$$\boxed{a^4 + b^4 + c^4 ≥ a + b + c}$$
where equality holds if and only if $a = b = c = 1$. $\blacksquare$

Case 2 is even simpler: just note that $|a|+|b|+|c|\ge a+b+c$.

Here is a solution by using sum of squares $\geq 0$. Homogenize the initial inequality to get
$$a^4 + b^4 + c^4 \geq abc(a+b+c)$$
But is true for $a,b,c\in \mathbb R$ that $$(a^2-b^2)^2 + (b^2-c^2)^2 + (c^2-a^2)^2 + (ac-bc)^2 + (ab-ac)^2 + (bc-ab)^2\geq 0$$
which is equivalent to $2a^4 + 2b^4 + 2c^4 - 2a^2bc - 2b^2ac - 2c^2ab\geq 0$ which is the same as $a^4+b^4+c^4\geq abc(a+b+c)$.

This doesn't answer the question. Ryan wants his idea to be verified.

It's an alternative method
